# Software with Workflow and Ticketing features

Tags: open-source, reporting, workflow, issue-tracker

I'm looking for a Software which is **combining workflow design** (actors, tasks, flow) and **ticketing** (actors can report on each task and for example join files).

The process I want to use it for is kind of :

1. Team manager receive a client request for a service (risk analysis
   in my case)
2. Team manager affect the task to one of his employee
3. The employee plans and affects tasks (himself included)
4. Others do the different tasks and report in the tool

This is the global process. The purpose is : **get a flow of tasks and get some infos about "what's in progress ?" (to do some reporting on client side)**.

I looked around a lot and document myself on a lot of solutions : Request tracker, Jira, ProcessMaker, OSTicket, Mantis, UserVoice, GLPI.
Those that fit best seem to be **ProcessMaker** and **Jira**, but they missed some functionnalities and seem a bit "overkill" for my purpose.

If you have any idea of Open Source, Pay as You Go or paying software, please let me know...

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: GLPi partner

GLPi seems to address exactly your needs. Give it a try.
You can go with Open Source (community support), SaaS or Hire support from a teclib GLPi partner.